# Pasting url in file window stopped working and prompts "You can't open this location using this program"

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm a webdev and work a lot with images from the internet. I've always been able to just copy the url of an image and then paste it in the "Open file" window, which would automatically save the image to my temp folder and use it for whatever the "open file" window was used for.

So for example, if I want to upload an image to some website, I'll copy the url of the image, click the "Browse..." button on the target website, hit "Ctrl+V" which pastes in the image url in the "Filename" field, I hit "Enter" and the image is uploaded to the website without me purposefully saving it somewhere on my PC.

However, since about a week that no longer works. When I try it the "Open file" window closes when I hit enter, but no image is selected or uploaded. When I then click the "Browse..." button again I'll get an error saying "You can't open this location using this program".

[image: Example of the error (in Dutch)]

Does anyone have a fix for this because I'm losing my mind over it. I work a lot with our company's CMS for clients and it requires me to upload a lot of images that are hosted somewhere else on the internet. This is forcing me to manually save every image to a folder, then upload the file from my PC adding multiple extra steps which stack over a workday.

---

Here's a short video (the system language is in Dutch tho). Normally when I'd press the "Openen" button the image would just upload: https://youtu.be/J-gVq5Hlsuo

---

**Edit**

There seems to be more going on, I just noticed that when I save an image to my desktop, then click a "Browse..." button and select the saved image, my Windows taskbar disappears briefly as if it crashes and restarts. If there's one negative thing to say about Windows 10, it's that they seriously crippled Explorer. It's super unstable, slow, and things that should just work as a base of the OS sometimes don't.

I don't want to tell you how often I press the Start button on my keyboard and the Start menu doesn't open, or the times that Explorer hangs, or the fact that every time I open a folder with more than 20 files in it I first get the empty screen with "Working on it..." for 10 seconds or longer.

Comment: I feel your pain, Windows 10 is an abomination. I would run a chkdsk on the C partition, see if there are any file system issues.

Comment: @Moab This seems to be happing both on my home PC and work PC though, maybe a faulty Windows update?

Comment: forums are full of W10 issues after updates or version upgrades. W10 is now a huge bag of crap that continually upgrades to even a bigger bag of crap. Sorry I have no clue how to fix your problem.